# Adding a user to a shared mailbox in Office 365 Admin Center

Tags: office365

I am trying to add a user to a shared mailbox in Office 365 Admin Center. The user is on our local AD which is synced to Office 365. The user is showing  under Active Users but when I go to the shared mailbox and try to add the user I am not able to see the user in the list. I can add other users fine. The user was set up same as other users and is in same AD groups. Thanks.

Comment: has the user been on the system for some time, or just recently been created?

Comment: Hi, the user was set up on system over a year ago.